# Sqoop making column as null for long text in sqoop export

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop, amazon-emr

I am trying to export records from S3 to Mysql Aurora using sqoop export .
One of the data type in S3 is like clob and the its long text and XML file is stored in it as string .
When i run my sqoop job it runs fine but in Mysql this column value comes as blank space not as null  .

Is there anyway i can make long text appear in mysql table as well ?

This is my sqoop export

```
sqoop export \
--direct \
--connect jdbc:mysql://abcd.amazonaws.com/FSP \
--username admin \
--password Welcome123 \
--table AUDIT_EVENT \
--export-dir s3://abcd/DMS/FSP/AUDIT_EVENT \
-num-mappers 25 \
--fields-terminated-by  ',' \
--batch \
--input-lines-terminated-by '\n' \
-- --default-character-set=latin1
```

I did try to use this option as well 
-`-map-column-hive DETAILS=String` 
But when i select i see blank space in the table .

Answer (score 1):

So you this and you will see the value

```
--map-column-java DETAILS=String
```